# Animating over a Window

Tags: wpf, animation, blend

I have a program where the user needs to navigate through back and forth. Basically there's {Dashboard, Settings ... }
I implemented them using a User Control, so I have my Window, and my User Controls that load in it.
The page switcher code I used to navigate between them I found there (azerdark.wordpress.com/2010/04/23/multi-page-application-in-wpf)

What I want is to animate the way the User Controls navigate when they are loaded in my window.
The simplest thing I found would be to create a Frame over my Window and animate it .. which I did, but I'm having trouble raising the event that fires the animation. I tried animating on window loaded just for testing and it works fine, but when the User Controls are loaded in my windows the animation is not working.

Here's my code
XAML: {PageSwitcher - My Window where the User Controls are loaded}

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="FadeLeft">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="myFrame">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="900">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseOut" Exponent="5"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseOut" Exponent="5"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="myFrame">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="myFrame">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <PowerEase EasingMode="EaseOut" Power="2"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="1">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <PowerEase EasingMode="EaseOut" Power="2"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>

<Frame x:Name="myFrame" Content="" Background="#FF8F4646" Visibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="x:Static local:PageSwitcher.ainmate">
            <ei:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource FadeLeft}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <Frame.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform/>
            <SkewTransform/>
            <RotateTransform/>
            <TranslateTransform/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </Frame.RenderTransform>
</Frame>
```

XAML.cs

```
    public static readonly RoutedEvent animate = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
        "Fade", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(PageSwitcher));

    public event RoutedEventHandler Fade
    {
        add { AddHandler(animate, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(animate, value); }
    }

    public void RaiseAnimateEvent()
    {
        RoutedEventArgs newEventArgs = new RoutedEventArgs(PageSwitcher.animate);
        RaiseEvent(newEventArgs);
    }
```

The event for the animation gets raised in my Switcher class just before Navigate is called to load the content of the User Control into my Window

XAML.cs  {Switcher -- only sets the content of my window to the User Control passed when Navigate is called.}

```
    public static void Switch(UserControl newPage)
    {
        pageSwitcher.Navigate(newPage);
        pageSwitcher.RaiseAnimateEvent();
    }
```

Is there anything wrong with my code? Why isn't the animation working?
The frame doesn't show when I navigate between the UserControls

Thanks for any help